# c$50 finance non-integers being rejected causing Buy to fail check50

Tags: python, html, flask

Everything seems to be working fine with my code, however I am running into a single error for `/buy` when running `check50`. :( buy handles fractional, negative, and non-numeric shares. expected status code 400, but got 200.

I thinks `check50` is receiving status code 200 when checking a non-integer such as `1.5` or string, before the buy form can even be submitted.

Flask app:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
    if request.method == "POST":
        ticket = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

        if not ticket:
            return apology("Stock symbol not correct!")

        cash = rows[0]["cash"]

        if "." in request.form.get("shares") or "/" in request.form.get("shares") or "," in request.form.get("shares"):
            return apology("Number of shares must be a positive integer!")

        try:
            shares = float(request.form.get("shares"))

        except:
            return apology("Number of shares must be a positive integer!")

        if (ticket["price"] * shares) > cash:
            return apology("Sorry you don't have sufficient amount of cash!")

        transaction = db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (username, company, symbol, shares, transaction_type, transaction_price) VALUES (:username, :company, :symbol, :share, :transaction_type, :transaction_price)",
                                 username=rows[0]["username"], company=ticket["name"], symbol=ticket["symbol"], share=shares, transaction_type="buy", transaction_price=ticket["price"] * shares)
        if not transaction:
            return apology("Error while making the transaction!")

        else:
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :new WHERE id = :id", new=cash - ticket["price"] * shares, id=session["user_id"])
            return index()

    else:
        return render_template("buy.html", balance=usd(rows[0]["cash"]), check=True)`




def apology(message, code=400):
    """Render message as an apology to user."""
    def escape(s):
        """
        Escape special characters.

        https://github.com/jacebrowning/memegen#special-characters
        """
        for old, new in [("-", "--"), (" ", "-"), ("_", "__"), ("?", "~q"),
                         ("%", "~p"), ("#", "~h"), ("/", "~s"), ("\"", "''")]:
            s = s.replace(old, new)
        return s
    return render_template("apology.html", top=code, bottom=escape(message)), code`
```

HTML Code

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Buy
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Your available balance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ balance }}</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol of stock" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="shares" type="number" min="1" required />
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

If `shares` is a non-integer it should render template `apology.html` via `apology` function with return code 400. Instead `check50` is detecting return code 200.

Does anybody else have this problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Questions like yours on StackOverflow are best if they are a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem, that's probably why people aren't responding.  There's more explanation in the link, but the gist is that you should try to isolate the part of the code that's causing the issue, and include everything people need to answer.  For instance, what's `check50`?  Is that the name of your Flask app?  You never actually say.

Comment: Thanks for feedback I'm new to stackoverflow and I did not know how to properly form a question. Meanwhile I was able to solve the problem. The problem was that the python code did not check for negative numbers and therefore accepted them (which should not).
PS: Check50 is a tool in CS50 course to check the correctness of your code. I was hoping for a feedback from people who took the course. Maybe I should have been more specific. Thanks again for feedback

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. The problem was that the python code did not check for negative numbers and therefore accepted them (which should not).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by taking the shares value from the form and putting it into a try block to typecast it into an int, if it receives a value error (if they have a decimal in the string) then it returns the apology page.

If can typecast without any issue then it means that the user entered in a whole number and the program moves along to the next steps.

```
        try:
            shares_check = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        except ValueError:
            return apology("Shares must be in whole numbers")
```

You seem to be 95% the way there with your try-block but you are checking for floats and trying to handle the decimal in a more complex than needed way.